# The symbol "* was inserted before "=" to continue

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

```
create or replace trigger check_status BEFORE update on LDS_PLACEMENT
for each row declare STATUS LDS_PLACEMENT.STATUS%type;
begin
STATUS :=old.STATUS;
if STATUS := 'Closed' then
raise_application_error(-20111,'Sorry the placement is closed');
end if;
end;
```

I get error at line 5. The code is not compiling.

This is for an academic assignment.

Comment: What is the error (message)?

Comment: You need a collation as  `STATUS = 'Closed'`, but not an assignment. That's the reason for the error. Just remove `:` in  `STATUS := 'Closed'`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `:` from the equal in the if statement

:= means your assigning value like you did above in the `old.status`

```
create or replace trigger check_status BEFORE update on LDS_PLACEMENT
for each row declare STATUS LDS_PLACEMENT.STATUS%type;
begin
STATUS := :old.STATUS;

if STATUS = 'Closed' then
raise_application_error(-20111,'Sorry the placement is closed');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: identifier 'OLD.STATUS' must be declaredCompilation failed, line 3 (14:14:31) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers

Comment: @SuyeshBhatta ok check now, added `:` in `:old.status`